# Yii user rights extension

Tags: php, yii

i have installed the yii rights extension and here is my code after installation, database tables are created after installation.

```
'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

            'rights'=>array( 
             'superuserName'=>'Admin',   // Name of the role with super user privileges.    
             'authenticatedName'=>'Authenticated',  //// Name of the authenticated user role.
                  'userIdColumn'=>'id',// Name of the user id column in the database.   
                   'userNameColumn'=>'username', //     Name of the user name column in the database.  
                   'enableBizRule'=>true, // Whether to enable authorization item business rules.    
                   'enableBizRuleData'=>false, //Whether to enable data for business rules.   
                         'displayDescription'=>true,  // Whether to use item description instead of name.    '
                          // Key to use for setting success flash messages.  
                            'flashErrorKey'=>'RightsError',  
                            / Key to use for setting error flash messages.    
                          //  'install'=>true,    // Whether to install rights.    
                            'baseUrl'=>'/rights', // Base URL for Rights. Change if module is nested.   
                              'layout'=>'rights.views.layouts.main',  // Layout to use for displaying Rights.    
                              'appLayout'=>'application.views.layouts.main', //Application layout.  
                                 'cssFile'=>'rights.css',   // Style sheet file to use for Rights.    '
                                 'install'=>false,  // Whether to enable installer.
                                        'debug'=>false,
                    ),


        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'1234',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),

    ),
```

But when i type url `http://localhost/rightsTest/index.php/rights` then it says

```
Error 403
There must be at least one superuser!
```

I have tried many things but unable to find answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you check whether the account you specified to be superuser actually exists? Maybe in your database it is called "admin" and not "Admin".

Comment: i did not get you, you are talking about which database table? i think its this extension that creates 4 tables in database. Authassignment,authitem,authitemchild,rights. May i ask which table you are talking about?

Comment: Well, you have a user table somewhere – after all the user data has to be pulled from somewhere. That source of information is what I am talking about.

Comment: Yes i have a user table and i have checked it, same error 403 occurs.

Comment: Mhh, the creator of the extension published a document ([pdf](http://yii-rights.googlecode.com/files/yii-rights-doc-1.2.0.pdf)) that includes a step by step explanation to install it. How much of it did you read/follow?

Comment: @NikolasGrottendieck i am following this document step by step.Installation part went well but now i am stuck at this point.

Comment: Just a sidenote, the creator of rights created another application to handle authorizations that is less buggy and more flexible than rights: https://github.com/Crisu83/yii-auth

Comment: And if your user class is not named User youshould add in the config the param `userClass`

Comment: @NikolasGrottendieck i have tried many times and checked different things but unsuccessful. Can you please help me about, that if yii rights extension is implemented in app and i get roles using this extension. If in the same app if i use the authManager methods to find the roles, will it bring me the same roles as the extension? would not it be conflicting with the extension?

Comment: @jailedabroad, sorry but I don't have much experience with Yii-Rights in particular. I used it a year or two ago for a short while but never in depth. If possible at all you may wish switch to Yii-Auth as suggested by darkheir.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a user table with id, username fileds and you must check if there is atleast one record in that table. Because rights choose the first record in the user table as the Admin role.

Answer (score 1):

Create new admin user. There is one "user" table in database which is of rights moudle, make entry of your admin user with "username", "password" of your choice and dont forget to set "superuser" and "status" field values to 1....

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specify the super user in config file.

1. Open protected->config->main.php file in your yii installation.
2. Find following piece of lines related to Rights configurations.

   ```
       'rights'=>array( 
             'install'=>false, // Enables the installer. 
             'userNameColumn'=>'user_name',
             'userClass'=>'Users',
             'superuserName'=>'your_superuser_username'
       ),
   ```
3. Enter your superuser **username** as the value of 'superuserName'.
4. Save main.php

and try to reload rights. Problem will be solved. :)

NB: make sure your User Class and user_name column of your user table is also specified here correctly. Otherwise you may face to another issue. Happy coding! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have same Problem, and i add my superuser name in RAuthorizer. in rights/component/RAuthorizer

```
$superusers = array('beautiful'); // Beautiful is my superadmin username
foreach( $users as $user )
$superusers[] = $user->name;

    if( $superusers===array() )
    throw new CHttpException(403, Rights::t('core', 'There must be at least one superuser!'));
    return $superusers;
```

And it works.